# How to check which application are using most resources?

Tags: monitoring, cpu, processes

How can I monitor which application are using most resources such as RAM and CPU? How do I disable them?

Comment: use the `top` command in the terminal that comes when you press `super+t`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Option 1: Install GNOME System Monitor with the Software Center

1. Open up the Software Center from the Applications menu
2. Search for GNOME System Monitor
3. Select GNOME System Monitor from the results and click install.
4. You can now launch the GNOME System Monitor. It will look something like this:

[image: GNOME System Monitor - Resources Tab]

[image: GNOME System Monitor - Processes Tab]

#### Option 2: Install the GNOME System Monitor in the Terminal

1. Open the Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
   ```
3. Follow the onscreen instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KzzotAAb9L471PO17Iiojq7jmm47ky5ceFNnHu0u5lA/edit) will help you.

The terminal is capable of showing you running processes via the `top` command.
All you need to do is open a terminal, whether on your desktop or, if things have frozen by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>  - <kbd>F12</kbd>, logging in and entering the `top` command.

Comment: drum, It's generally best to list the technique, steps, or commands needed, and then reference the source, rather than just posting a link, since links die. @Jay Thank you for the edit.